# Floating point exceptions,segmentation faults and similar errors

Tags: c++, floating-point-exceptions

I sometimes get this type of errors. My question is, is there a way to find out information about when and where(which line) exactly this error occurs? I'm on ubuntu linux 14.04. Using sublime and g++.

Here is my current code. I get a floating point exception in this. It takes 2 vectors and prints the numbers that are divisible by every element of the first set and can divide every element of the second set.

Posting the code is kinda irrelavant to the topic but it forced me to find a decent way to debug the mentioned error types.

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> firstVector;
    vector<int> secondVector;
    firstVector = {2,4};
    secondVector = {16,32,96};
    auto it = firstVector.begin();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
    {
       it = firstVector.begin();
        for (; ; ++it)
        {
            if(i%(*it)!=0)
                break;
            if(it==firstVector.end())
            {
                it=secondVector.begin();
                while(it!=secondVector.end())
                {
                    if((*it)%i!=0)
                    {
                        it=firstVector.begin();
                        break;
                    }
                    it++;
                }
            }
            if(it==secondVector.end())
                break;
        }
        if(it==secondVector.end())
            cout << i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Where is your test data?  And if you have that, hard-code the data in the program instead of using `cin` and wearing out the keyboard every time the program is run.

Comment: I'm not sure why I haven't used a test data. Never needed it I guess? Also, this is a solution for a code challenge hence the "cin".

Comment: I miss Visual Studio already...

Comment: Just set `firstVector` and `secondVector` to known values that duplicate the issue, i.e. `std::vector<int> firstVector = { 0, 43, 27,...}` etc.  That way we can not only see what the data is, we can copy and paste your code into the compiler, compile, and run your program without constantly having a `cin` stop us and having to always type something in.

Comment: Is the question "How to use a debugger?" or "why does this code fail?"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is a problem in iteration over `firstVector` and `secondVector`. In second loop:

```
 auto it = firstVector.begin();
 for (; ; ++it)
 {
```

`it` is iterator for `firstVector`. But in the next loop:

```
 it=secondVector.begin();
 while(it!=secondVector.end())
 {
```

`it` becomes iterator for the `secondVector`. Iteration over `it` continues in the outer `for` loop after this `while` loop. You increment `++it` and access elements `if(i%(*it)!=0)` at and after the `.end()` element. This leads to [UB](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end):

> This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.

Comment: That was a brilliant edit. I was trying to understand so hard what you were saying.

Comment: Check the updated code. For every iteration of the outmost "for" loop "it" gets reassigned to firstVector.begin(). If the while loop ends because "it" reaches .end() then the program also breaks out from the "for" loop in the middle(check line. 39). I'm at a loss here.

Comment: @yavuz650 In the updated code there is the new problem. If expression`it==firstVector.end()` is not `true` than you compare `it==secondVector.end()`, but `it` is the iterator for `firstVector`. Such comaprision is invalid. Don't mix iterators, use different variables for `firstVector` and `secondVector` iterators.

Answer (score 0):

This question is kind of a two-parter. Since Nikita already addressed your code...

> My question is, is there a way to find out information about when and where(which line) exactly this error occurs?

Use `gdb name-of-executable` to debug on Linux. Simply `run` and the program will break when a seg fault occurs or, I believe, a fatal exception is thrown. It will tell you the file name and line number.

You can also look up more gdb commands, like here: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html

Comment: Make sure to compile with `-O0` so that line numbers don't get optimized out.